# Can I remove an edit from the queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I don't have enough rep to make edits right away on posts, so when I edit a post it always tells me, "Thanks! Please wait till it has been peer reviewed, it has been added to the editing queue" type of thing.

However just recently, I edited a post basically at the same time as someone else.
When I finished my edit and clicked "Edit post", it said that the poster had edited the post 38 seconds ago.

Now of course this being the poster's own post, and their edit was better, I felt ashamed and wanted to remove my edit from the queue, as it is no longer nessacary.

Could one go about doing this, removing an edit they posted from a queue? How would one do it if they could?

<strike>As a side note, sorry to [pixel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/27134/pixel) for my proposed edit [on this question,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80842/25368) yours was a much better edit</strike>

Comment: Don't worry about it! :P

Comment: @pixel didn't want someone silly to go ahead and accept my edit after yours :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once an edit has been submitted there doesn't appear to be a way to revoke the edit - it simply sits in the moderation queue waiting to be processed. One potentially suitable solution would be to pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) and highlight it so that somebody with enough rep can reject it for you.

There are no negative effects to having an edit rejected or improved upon, so don't worry about that.

There certainly is nothing to be ashamed of though, I certainly have done this myself before and I'm sure we're not alone in this particular situation :)

Comment: Ah chat makes sounds like a good idea! Thanks!

Comment: *There are no negative effects to having an edit rejected or improved upon.*  Note, however, that several rejections in a short period will cause an edit ban.

Comment: @JohntheGreen It's worth mentioning that that edit ban is temporary. It lasts 7 days.

Comment: @AnnaLear I thought there was also a permanent version for repeat offenders?